# Different column width in 2 rows with bootstrap and custom post types-different classes needed

Tags: custom-post-types, php, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm using a custom post type on my WP website and also using bootstrap.

I want to list 5 custom post type entries on my home page, and I want the first 3 to have class col-md-4 in one row and in the next row 2 cpt entries to have the class col-md-6

At the moment I have a class col-md-4 and 2 items in the 2nd row are not centered nicely.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid gray-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        $projects = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'project','posts_per_page'=>5, 'order'=>'ASC'));
                        if ($projects) { ?>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <?php foreach ($projects as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
                                <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
                                    <a class="highlights-item" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <div class="highlights-container">
                                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                                    <span class="highlights-title">
                                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </ul>
                                            <?php }
                                ?>  

                            </div> <!-- end row -->
                        </div> <!-- end container -->
                    </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below.

```
<div class="container-fluid gray-section">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <?php 
                                    $projects = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'project','posts_per_page'=>5, 'order'=>'ASC'));
                                    if ($projects) { ?>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <?php $i = 0; ?>
                      <?php foreach ($projects as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
        <?php if($i % 3 == 1) { ?>
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
        <?php } else if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i > 0) { ?>
        <li class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-xxs-12 text-center ">
        <?php } ?>**
                                                <a class="highlights-item" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                                    <div class="highlights-container">
                                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                                                <span class="highlights-title">
                                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                                </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
    <?php $i++; ?>
                                                                <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                        </ul>
                                                        <?php }
                                            ?>  

                                        </div> <!-- end row -->
                                    </div> <!-- end container -->
                                </div> <!-- end container fluid -->
```